# Javascript - If and or statements - IE Undefined

Tags: javascript

I am so confused as to why this wont work...

In chrome when I click the button that runs this script, the textbox that pops up is empty, so I check for the length > 0.....

In IE, it populates it as undefined, so I thought I could just check the value and say if != undefined...

```
if (strTemp.length > 0) {
    if (strTemp.value != "undefined") {
        printLabels(strCarrier, strTemp);
    } else {
        alert('You wont get labels until you tell us why...');
    }
}
else {
    alert('You wont get labels until you tell us why...');
}
```

Anybody have any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: undefined isn't the same as the string undefined...

Comment: undefined shouldnt be a string

Comment: use `if (strTemp.length > 0 && strTemp.value != undefined)`

Comment: @maioman Should be the other way. First check undefined, then length.

Comment: I thought it didn't matter but I'll take your word on it :)

Comment: @maioman Your way, if it is undefined, you'd throw a `Can't read property "length" of undefined` error. My way, it returns false (due to short-circuiting) before hitting that.

Comment: yes you're right , I was just reading about that (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)

Comment: @Scimonster ... if (strTemp.length > 0 && strTemp.value != undefined) does not work... Even when I type in testest it still bombs out... Any idea why?

Answer (score 4):

If the value is `undefined`, it's not a string. You should be checking `if (strTemp.value != undefined)`.

See [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) on MDN.

Comment: Or use typeof and compare to string.

Comment: So this didnt seem to work, because with this set of code now, it wont let anything go through?

Comment: `if ((strTemp.length > 0) && (!(strTemp.value == undefined))){
    printLabels(strCarrier, strTemp);
   } else {
    alert('You wont get labels until you tell us why...');
   }`

Comment: @KyleRickaby Try placing the undefined check before the length check.

Comment: @Scimonster Wont work either, I just typed nothing in chrome and it gave me the alert... I typed test and it gave me the alert :(

Comment: What type of thing is strTemp? If it's a String, there is no `value` property on it, so that's why it may be throwing an error. Instead use `if (strTemp && strTemp.length)`.

Answer (score 2):

Undefined is a data type, not a string value. If you want to compare to a string, try using this:

```
if (typeof strTemp.value === "undefined") {
    alert("strTemp.val is undefined");
}
```

Comment: `if ((strTemp.length > 0) && (typeof strTemp.value === "undefined")){
    printLabels(strCarrier, strTemp);
   } else {
    alert('You wont get labels until you tell us why...');
   }`

Comment: Works in chrome but not in IE when it is set as undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strTemp && strTemp.value) {
    printLabels(strCarrier, strTemp);
} else {
    alert('You wont get labels until you tell us why...');
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: `if (strTemp && strTemp.value) {
    printLabels(strCarrier, strTemp);
} else {
    alert('You wont get labels until you tell us why...');
}`

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anybody is wondering... This is how I ended up solving it....

```
if (strTemp.length > 1) {
            if ((strTemp == "undefined") || (strTemp == "")){
                alert('You wont get labels until you tell us why...');
            }else{
                printLabels(strCarrier, strTemp);
            }
        }else{
            if ((strTemp == "undefined") || (strTemp == "")){
                alert('You wont get labels until you tell us why...');
            }else{
                printLabels(strCarrier, strTemp);
            }

        }
```